# Controlling Windows7 volume with midi

Tags: windows-7, midi

I have an external sound card and controller that can send midi signals to windows.
Is there a good free software that can get the midi signals and translate them to windows volume level change?
I know it is possible as all the thing works in special music software (I can adjust the software controls to be controlled by my controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is at least one.

[Midi2Master.Vol](https://web.archive.org/web/20140915192821/http://strobotone.de/interface/html/other_works/dev) ([direct link to ZIP](http://web300.xps12.microserver.de/content/development/midi2master.vol/midi2master.vol.zip))

> control your windows master volume using a midi controller!

You can perhaps also rig something up using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and a user-created [Midi-In plugin](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/28056-midi-input-library/) for AHK.

Answer (score 0):

I just released another Audio related gadget for Win Vista/7/8:

mVControl (MIDI Volume Control) lets you control output and input volumes via MIDI controller and -keys and runs in the background.

This is useful for people who want to control their audio levels using existing MIDI hardware without having to open any user interface. Set and forget.

Get it here : [mVControl.zip](http://strobotone.de/content/development/mVControl/mVControl.zip)

Not the most beautiful UI but it gets the job done. Again, it is my software.